# How to use a static resource of string for the value of DataTrigger bound with a combo box SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using some ComboBoxes that their ComboBoxItems are a set of StaticResource of strings. I want to change the visibility of a ComboBox to collapsed when one of the item of another ComboBox is selected, by using its SeletedItem NOT SelectedIndex.

For doing so, I wrote the following code, but the Visual Studio shows this error message:"After a 'DataTrigger' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified."

```
<Window x:Class="CB.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CB"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="177" Width="179">
<Window.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="Str1">String1</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Str2">String2</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Str3">String3</system:String>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CB1">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource Str1}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource Str2}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource Str3}"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CB2">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{StaticResource Str3}">
                                                                              <!--Error ^: After a 'DataTrigger' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified. --> 
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource Str1}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource Str2}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource Str3}"/>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Would you please help me with this issue, possibly using WPF code?

**EDIT:** Please somebody answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MultiDataTrigger instead DataTrigger and use a ComboBoxItemToStringConverter:

```
public class ComboBoxItemToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var combo = value as ComboBoxItem;
        string content = combo?.Content.ToString();
        return content;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then You use:

```
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <local:ComboBoxItemToStringConverter x:Key="ObjectToStringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxItemToStringConverter}}" Value="{StaticResource Str3}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

I hope it works for you.

Edit: If you don't want to use c# code. Instead of using "SelectedItem" use Text:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=Text}" Value="{StaticResource Str3}" />
```

And remove the Converter.

Comment: Isn't there any WPF solutions, without using C# code?

Comment: Hello. I found the solution to not use code: <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=Text}" Value="{StaticResource Str3}" />